# How can I solve this error related to Supersonic SDK?

Tags: unity-game-engine, android-unity-plugin

I have been trying to upload the SuperSonic SDK in my game. But I am getting these errors. I am not able to figure out what the error is, since I am new to Unity and Android. Kindly help me out

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to convert classes into dex format. See the Console for details.
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_73.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Xmx2048M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="/Users/name/Downloads/sdk/tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "/Applications/Unity/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools/sdktools.jar" -

stderr[
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/immersion/content/EndpointWarp;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/immersion/content/HapticHeaderUtils;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/immersion/content/HeaderUtils;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/immersion/content/Log;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/immersion/hapticmediasdk/HapticContentSDK;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/immersion/hapticmediasdk/HapticContentSDK$SDKStatus;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/immersion/hapticmediasdk/HapticContentSDKFactory;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/immersion/hapticmediasdk/HapticMediaSDKVersion;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/immersion/hapticmediasdk/MediaPlaybackSDK;

UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Translation has been interrupted
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:608)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:311)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at SDKMain.main(SDKMain.java:129)
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException: Too many errors
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:600)
    ... 9 more
]
stdout[
processing archive /Volumes/Development/Projects/Gusteau/Source/StarChefUnity_2/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/GoogleCloudMessaging_lib/libs/./GoogleCloudMessagingPlugin.jar...
ignored resource META-INF/
ignored resource META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
ignored resource com/
ignored resource com/prime31/
processing com/prime31/GCMBroadcastReceiver.class...
processing com/prime31/GoogleCloudMessagingPlugin.class...
processing com/prime31/GoogleCloudMessagingPlugin$1.class...
processing com/prime31/GoogleCloudMessagingPlugin$2.class...
processing com/prime31/GoogleCloudMessagingPlugin$3.class...
processing com/prime31/GoogleCloudMessagingPlugin$4.class...
processing com/prime31/GoogleCloudMessagingPlugin$CloudRegistrationTask.class...
processing com/prime31/GoogleCloudMessagingPlugin$CloudSendMessageTask.class...
processing com/prime31/GoogleCloudMessagingPlugin$CloudUnregistrationTask.class...
processing com/prime31/GoogleCloudMessagingPluginBase.class...
processing com/prime31/GoogleCloudMessagingPluginBase$1.class...
processing com/prime31/PushPrefs.class...
processing archive /Volumes/Development/Projects/Gusteau/Source/StarChefUnity_2/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/IAB_lib/libs/./IABPlugin.jar...
ignored resource META-INF/
ignored resource META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
ignored resource com/
ignored resource com/android/
ignored resource com/android/vending/
ignored resource com/android/vending/billing/
ignored resource com/android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService.aidl
processing com/android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService.class...
processing com/android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService$Stub.class...
processing com/android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService$Stub$Proxy.class...
ignored resource com/prime31/
processing com/prime31/GoogleIABPlugin.class...
processing com/prime31/GoogleIABPlugin$1.class...
processing com/prime31/GoogleIABPlugin$2.class...
processing com/prime31/GoogleIABPlugin$3.class...
processing com/prime31/GoogleIABPlugin$4.class...
processing com/prime31/GoogleIABPlugin$5.class...
processing com/prime31/GoogleIABPluginBase.class...
processing com/prime31/GoogleIABPluginBase$1.class...
processing com/prime31/GoogleIABProxyActivity.class...
processing com/prime31/IABConstants.class...
ignored resource com/prime31/InAppBilling/
processing com/prime31/InAppBilling/BuildConfig.class...
processing com/prime31/InAppBilling/R.class...
processing com/prime31/InAppBilling/R$attr.class...
processing com/prime31/InAppBilling/R$drawable.class...
processing com/prime31/InAppBilling/R$id.class...
processing com/prime31/InAppBilling/R$layout.class...
processing com/prime31/InAppBilling/R$menu.class...
processing com/prime31/InAppBilling/R$string.class...
processing com/prime31/InAppBilling/R$style.class...
ignored resource com/prime31/util/
processing com/prime31/util/Base64.class...
processing com/prime31/util/Base64DecoderException.class...
processing com/prime31/util/IabException.class...
processing com/prime31/util/IabHelper.class...
processing com/prime31/util/IabHelper$1.class...
processing com/prime31/util/IabHelper$2.class...
processing com/prime31/util/IabHelper$2$1.class...
processing com/prime31/util/IabHelper$3.class...
processing com/prime31/util/IabHelper$3$1.class...
processing com/prime31/util/IabHelper$3$2.class...
processing com/prime31/util/IabHelper$OnConsumeFinishedListener.class...
processing com/prime31/util/IabHelper$OnConsumeMultiFinishedListener.class...
processing com/prime31/util/IabHelper$OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener.class...
processing com/prime31/util/IabHelper$OnIabSetupFinishedListener.class...
processing com/prime31/util/IabHelper$QueryInventoryFinishedListener.class...
processing com/prime31/util/IabResult.class...
processing com/prime31/util/Inventory.class...
processing com/prime31/util/Purchase.class...
processing com/prime31/util/Security.class...
processing com/prime31/util/SkuDetails.class...
processing archive /Volumes/Development/Projects/Gusteau/Source/StarChefUnity_2/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/Localytics_lib/libs/./LocalyticsPlugin.jar...
ignored resource META-INF/
ignored resource META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
ignored resource com/
ignored resource com/prime31/
processing com/prime31/LocalyticsPlugin.class...
processing com/prime31/LocalyticsPluginBase.class...
processing com/prime31/LocalyticsPluginBase$1.class...
processing archive /Volumes/Development/Projects/Gusteau/Source/StarChefUnity_2/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/Localytics_lib/libs/./localytics.jar...
ignored resource META-INF/
ignored resource META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
ignored resource com/
ignored resource com/localytics/
ignored resource com/localytics/android/
processing com/localytics/android/AnalyticsHandler.class...
processing com/localytics/android/AnalyticsHandler$1.class...
processing com/localytics/android/AnalyticsHandler$10.class...
processing com/localytics/android/AnalyticsHandler$11.class...
processing com/localytics/android/AnalyticsHandler$12.class...
processing com/localytics/android/AnalyticsHandler$13.class...
processing com/localytics/android/AnalyticsHandler$14.class...
processing com/localytics/android/AnalyticsHandler$15.class...
processing com/localytics/android/AnalyticsHandler$16.class...
processing com/localytics/android/AnalyticsHandler$17.class...
processing com/localytics/android/AnalyticsHandler$18.class...
processing com/localytics/android/AnalyticsHandler$2.class...
processing com/localytics/android/AnalyticsHandler$3.class...
processing com/localytics/android/AnalyticsHandler$4.class...
processing com/localytics/android/AnalyticsHandler$5.class...
processing com/localytics/android/AnalyticsHandler$6.class...
processing com/localytics/android/AnalyticsHandler$7.class...
processing com/localytics/android/AnalyticsHandler$8.class...
processing com/localytics/android/AnalyticsHandler$9.class...
processing com/localytics/android/AnalyticsHandler$AnalyticsListenersSet.class...
processing com/localytics/android/AnalyticsListener.class...
processing com/localytics/android/AnalyticsProvider.class...
processing com/localytics/android/AnalyticsProvider$1.class...
processing com/localytics/android/AnalyticsProvider$AnalyticsDatabaseHelper.class...
processing com/localytics/android/AnalyticsProvider$CustomDimensionsV3Columns.class...
processing com/localytics/android/AnalyticsProvider$EventsV3Columns.class...
processing com/localytics/android/AnalyticsProvider$EventsV3Columns$UploadFormat.class...
processing com/localytics/android/AnalyticsProvider$IdentifiersV3Columns.class...
processing com/localytics/android/AnalyticsProvider$InfoV3Columns.class...
processing com/localytics/android/AnalyticsUploadHandler.class...
processing com/localytics/android/BaseHandler.class...
processing com/localytics/android/BaseHandler$1.class...
processing com/localytics/android/BaseHandler$2.class...
processing com/localytics/android/BaseHandler$3.class...
processing com/localytics/android/BaseHandler$BaseListener.class...
processing com/localytics/android/BaseHandler$ListenersSet.class...
processing com/localytics/android/BaseProvider.class...
processing com/localytics/android/BaseProvider$1.class...
processing com/localytics/android/BaseProvider$LocalyticsDatabaseHelper.class...
processing com/localytics/android/BaseUploadThread.class...
processing com/localytics/android/BaseUploadThread$UploadType.class...
processing com/localytics/android/BuildConfig.class...
processing com/localytics/android/Constants.class...
processing com/localytics/android/DatapointHelper.class...
processing com/localytics/android/DatapointHelper$AdvertisingInfo.class...
processing com/localytics/android/JavaScriptClient.class...
processing com/localytics/android/JavaScriptClient$1.class...
processing com/localytics/android/JsonHelper.class...
processing com/localytics/android/JsonObjects.class...
processing com/localytics/android/JsonObjects$BlobHeader.class...
processing com/localytics/android/JsonObjects$BlobHeader$Attributes.class...
processing com/localytics/android/JsonObjects$OptEvent.class...
processing com/localytics/android/JsonObjects$ProfileUpload.class...
processing com/localytics/android/JsonObjects$SessionClose.class...
processing com/localytics/android/JsonObjects$SessionEvent.class...
processing com/localytics/android/JsonObjects$SessionOpen.class...
processing com/localytics/android/Localytics.class...
processing com/localytics/android/Localytics$1.class...
processing com/localytics/android/Localytics$InAppMessageDismissButtonLocation.class...
processing com/localytics/android/Localytics$LocalyticsNotInitializedException.class...
processing com/localytics/android/Localytics$Log.class...
processing com/localytics/android/Localytics$ProfileScope.class...
processing com/localytics/android/LocalyticsActivity.class...
processing com/localytics/android/LocalyticsActivityLifecycleCallbacks.class...
processing com/localytics/android/LocalyticsActivityWithMarketing.class...
processing com/localytics/android/MarketingCallable.class...
processing com/localytics/android/MarketingCondition.class...
processing com/localytics/android/MarketingCondition$1.class...
processing com/localytics/android/MarketingCondition$Opt.class...
processing com/localytics/android/MarketingDialogFragment.class...
processing com/localytics/android/MarketingDialogFragment$1.class...
processing com/localytics/android/MarketingDialogFragment$1$1.class...
processing com/localytics/android/MarketingDialogFragment$2.class...
processing com/localytics/android/MarketingDialogFragment$MarketingDialog.class...
processing com/localytics/android/MarketingDialogFragment$MarketingDialog$1.class...
processing com/localytics/android/MarketingDialogFragment$MarketingDialog$2.class...
processing com/localytics/android/MarketingDialogFragment$MarketingDialog$3.class...
processing com/localytics/android/MarketingDialogFragment$MarketingDialog$4.class...
processing com/localytics/android/MarketingDialogFragment$MarketingDialog$5.class...
processing com/localytics/android/MarketingDialogFragment$MarketingDialog$CloseButton.class...
processing com/localytics/android/MarketingDialogFragment$MarketingDialog$MarketingWebView.class...
processing com/localytics/android/MarketingDialogFragment$MarketingDialog$MarketingWebView$MarketingWebViewClient.class...
processing com/localytics/android/MarketingDownloader.class...
processing com/localytics/android/MarketingHandler.class...
processing com/localytics/android/MarketingHandler$1.class...
processing com/localytics/android/MarketingHandler$10.class...
processing com/localytics/android/MarketingHandler$11.class...
processing com/localytics/android/MarketingHandler$12.class...
processing com/localytics/android/MarketingHandler$13.class...
processing com/localytics/android/MarketingHandler$13$1.class...
processing com/localytics/android/MarketingHandler$14.class...
processing com/localytics/android/MarketingHandler$15.class...
processing com/localytics/android/MarketingHandler$15$1.class...
processing com/localytics/android/MarketingHandler$16.class...
processing com/localytics/android/MarketingHandler$17.class...
processing com/localytics/android/MarketingHandler$18.class...
processing com/localytics/android/MarketingHandler$19.class...
processing com/localytics/android/MarketingHandler$2.class...
processing com/localytics/android/MarketingHandler$20.class...
processing com/localytics/android/MarketingHandler$21.class...
processing com/localytics/android/MarketingHandler$22.class...
processing com/localytics/android/MarketingHandler$23.class...
processing com/localytics/android/MarketingHandler$24.class...
processing com/localytics/android/MarketingHandler$3.class...
processing com/localytics/android/MarketingHandler$4.class...
processing com/localytics/android/MarketingHandler$5.class...
processing com/localytics/android/MarketingHandler$6.class...
processing com/localytics/android/MarketingHandler$6$1.class...
processing com/localytics/android/MarketingHandler$7.class...
processing com/localytics/android/MarketingHandler$7$1.class...
processing com/localytics/android/MarketingHandler$8.class...
processing com/localytics/android/MarketingHandler$8$1.class...
processing com/localytics/android/MarketingHandler$9.class...
processing com/localytics/android/MarketingHandler$MessagingListenersSet.class...
processing com/localytics/android/MarketingMessage.class...
processing com/localytics/android/MarketingProvider.class...
processing com/localytics/android/MarketingProvider$1.class...
processing com/localytics/android/MarketingProvider$MarketingConditionValuesV3Columns.class...
processing com/localytics/android/MarketingProvider$MarketingConditionsV3Columns.class...
processing com/localytics/android/MarketingProvider$MarketingDatabaseHelper.class...
processing com/localytics/android/MarketingProvider$MarketingDisplayedV3Columns.class...
processing com/localytics/android/MarketingProvider$MarketingRuleEventV3Columns.class...
processing com/localytics/android/MarketingProvider$MarketingRulesV3Columns.class...
processing com/localytics/android/MarketingRulesAdapter.class...
processing com/localytics/android/MarketingRulesAdapter$1.class...
processing com/localytics/android/MarketingRulesAdapter$2.class...
processing com/localytics/android/MessagingListener.class...
processing com/localytics/android/MigrationDatabaseHelper.class...
processing com/localytics/android/MigrationDatabaseHelper$1.class...
processing com/localytics/android/MigrationDatabaseHelper$AmpConditionValuesDbColumns.class...
processing com/localytics/android/MigrationDatabaseHelper$AmpConditionsDbColumns.class...
processing com/localytics/android/MigrationDatabaseHelper$AmpDisplayedDbColumns.class...
processing com/localytics/android/MigrationDatabaseHelper$AmpRuleEventDbColumns.class...
processing com/localytics/android/MigrationDatabaseHelper$AmpRulesDbColumns.class...
processing com/localytics/android/MigrationDatabaseHelper$ApiKeysD<message truncated>
```

What is the error all about  ? How can I solve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this line:

```
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/immersion/content/EndpointWarp;
```

This is the Problem. Somewhere in your project you have a duplicate android library. Unity is trying to convert all the classes to dex format but it's getting duplicates and it doesn't like that.

All you need to do is find the offending library and delete one of the copies. Doesn't matter which one.

Most likely the library will be a .jar file.